# Return Null Data

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2005

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MOSTAFA;Initial Catalog=mohasba;Integrated Security=True");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = con.CreateCommand();
da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select sum(مدين) AS مدين,sum (دائن) AS دائن  from  اذن_قيد  where اسم_البيان='" + comboBox1.SelectedIndex + "'";
da.Fill(ds, "اذن_قيد");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "اذن_قيد";
```

When i use this code, it return null data
But When i use this command in sql server "Return Data"

Comment: Please format the code so it is easily readable.  Also, I suggest using SQL Server Profiler to view the SQL actually running against the database, and try running that SQL in Query Ananlyzer.

Comment: Does `comboBox1.SelectedIndex` have a valid value for `اسم_البيان`?

Comment: I can't understand your query but noticed something in the where clause of your SelectCommand. You use combobox.SelectIndex which is a number but you put between in single quotes. Is the referenced field a string column?

Comment: This isn's specific to the problem, but why not use a DataTable instead of a DataSet, since you are only returning data from one SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any error with the code above.

What you can try is, First of all make sure that the connection string you are using can access the database.

Secondly, since you are using some kind of language coallation in your sql server queries, make sure that ASP.NET recongnizes the query and sends them to the sql server in the appropiate coallation.

Hope this helps.